# Juju incomplete Neutron installation

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

We have installed Openstack on distributed nodes using Juju + MAAS. Everything looks good, but Neutron cli is unresponsive.

```
user@controller:~$ nova list
+----+------+--------+------------+-------------+----------+
| ID | Name | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks |
+----+------+--------+------------+-------------+----------+
+----+------+--------+------------+-------------+----------+
user@controller:~$
user@controller:~$ neutron --version
2.3.4
user@controller:~$
user@controller:~$ neutron net-list
Connection to neutron failed: (504, 'Gateway Timeout')
user@controller:~$
```

If we press CRTL+C, we get:

```
user@controller:~$ neutron net-list
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/neutron", line 10, in <module>
   sys.exit(main())
<snip>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 239, in authenticate
   content_type="application/json")
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 146, in _cs_request
   resp, body = self.request(*args, **kargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1569, in request
   (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1316, in _request
   (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1251, in _conn_request
   conn.connect()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 900, in connect
   self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port) + sa[2:])
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/socks.py", line 424, in connect
   self.__negotiatehttp(destpair[0], destpair[1])
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/socks.py", line 374, in __negotiatehttp
   resp = self.recv(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Connectivity wise, all the services are on the same LAN and we can ping/ssh to all nodes. Some troubleshooting logs:

```
ubuntu@juju-machine-13-lxc-4:~$ cat /var/log/neutron/server.log | grep WARNING
<snip>
2015-05-12 04:21:47.680 32427 WARNING neutron.openstack.common.db.sqlalchemy.session [-] This application has not enabled MySQL traditional mode, which means silent data corruption may occur. Please encourage the application developers to enable this mode.
2015-05-12 04:21:48.386 32427 WARNING neutron.api.extensions [req-42b7d5c5-813d-470d-9a06-21e675c78ae5 None] Extension allowed-address-pairs not supported by any of loaded plugins
2015-05-12 04:21:48.398 32427 WARNING neutron.api.extensions [req-42b7d5c5-813d-470d-9a06-21e675c78ae5 None] Extension flavor not supported by any of loaded plugins
2015-05-12 04:21:48.415 32427 WARNING neutron.api.extensions [req-42b7d5c5-813d-470d-9a06-21e675c78ae5 None] Extension port-security not supported by any of loaded plugins
2015-05-12 04:21:48.419 32427 WARNING neutron.api.extensions [req-42b7d5c5-813d-470d-9a06-21e675c78ae5 None] Extension routed-service-insertion not supported by any of loaded plugins
2015-05-12 04:21:48.420 32427 WARNING neutron.api.extensions [req-42b7d5c5-813d-470d-9a06-21e675c78ae5 None] Extension router-service-type not supported by any of loaded plugins
2015-05-12 04:21:48.424 32427 WARNING neutron.api.extensions [req-42b7d5c5-813d-470d-9a06-21e675c78ae5 None] Extension security-group not supported by any of loaded plugins
2015-05-12 04:21:48.461 32427 WARNING keystoneclient.middleware.auth_token [-] Configuring auth_uri to point to the public identity endpoint is required; clients may not be able to authenticate against an admin endpoint
```

Neutron config:

```
ubuntu@juju-machine-13-lxc-4:~$ sudo cat /etc/neutron/neutron.conf
# icehouse
###############################################################################
# [ WARNING ]
# Configuration file maintained by Juju. Local changes may be overwritten.
## Restart trigger None
###############################################################################
<snip>
[keystone_authtoken]
signing_dir = /var/cache/neutron
service_protocol = http
service_host = 10.0.0.21
service_port = 5000
auth_host = 10.0.0.21
auth_port = 35357
auth_protocol =  http
admin_tenant_name = services
admin_user = quantum
admin_password = GY4BYj8M5Rx3FymxkJzMmbHcnVBTsxMG35nBJpN8VRcx3zxMbx6F4tBNbL4jTwyP
[database]
connection = mysql://neutron:h5rMNq6qbCx6hVhPWFPWHPNpZRNTnGbk@10.0.0.18/neutron
max_pool_size = 256
```

We noticed we didn’t have auth_uri on api-paste.ini

```
ubuntu@juju-machine-13-lxc-4:~$ sudo cat /etc/neutron/api-paste.ini
<snip>
[filter:authtoken]
paste.filter_factory = keystoneclient.middleware.auth_token:filter_factory
```

So we added to api-paste.ini the following, which cleared the auth_uri warning.

```
auth_host = 10.0.0.21
auth_uri = http://10.0.0.21:5000/v2.0
admin_tenant_name = services
admin_user = quantum
admin_password = GY4BYj8M5Rx3FymxkJzMmbHcnVBTsxMG35nBJpN8VRcx3zxMbx6F4tBNbL4jTwyP
```

On Horizon we initially had the following Network Agents:

- Open vSwitch agent

We executed the following on Network node:

```
ubuntu@juju-machine-13-lxc-4:~$ sudo apt-get install neutron-server neutron-dhcp-agent neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent neutron-l3-agent
Reading package lists… Done
<snip>
```

Which added some Network Agents:

- Open vSwitch agent
- Metadata agent
- DHCP agent

But that didn’t clear the other warnings and we still don’t see L3-agent nor we can execute Neutron cli commands. Any clue?

```
ubuntu@juju-machine-13-lxc-4:~$ dpkg -l | grep neutron
ii  neutron-common                   1:2014.1.4-0ubuntu2              all          Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack - common
ii  neutron-dhcp-agent               1:2014.1.4-0ubuntu2              all          Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack - DHCP agent
ii  neutron-l3-agent                 1:2014.1.4-0ubuntu2              all          Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack - l3 agent
ii  neutron-metadata-agent           1:2014.1.4-0ubuntu2              all          Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack - metadata agent
ii  neutron-plugin-ml2               1:2014.1.4-0ubuntu2              all          Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack - ML2 plugin
ii  neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent 1:2014.1.4-0ubuntu2              all          Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack - Open vSwitch plugin agent
ii  neutron-server                   1:2014.1.4-0ubuntu2              all          Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack - server
ii  python-neutron                   1:2014.1.4-0ubuntu2              all          Neutron is a virutal network service for Openstack - Python library
ii  python-neutronclient             1:2.3.4-0ubuntu1                 all          client - Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack
ubuntu@juju-machine-13-lxc-4:~$
```

We get same result with different charm combinations:

- quantum-gateway charm and setting network-manager as Neutron when
  running the nova-cloud-controller charm neutron-api and
- neutron-openvswitch charms with and without network-manager as
  Neutron when running the nova-cloud-controller charm

Thanks